# Splitting vector to get middle value

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

I have few column names from which I need to get middle string. For example;

From this list

```
"RHC3934__Bcell__.7DEA7B","RHC3944__Bcell__.7DEA7B",  "RHC3962__Tcell__.C6E879", "RHC4003__Bcell__.7DEA7B", "RHC4005__Bcell__.7DEA7B", "RHC4007__Bcell__.7DEA7B"
```

I need to get **"Bcell"** for each of the element.

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: you need to get the which element has Bcell in it ?

Comment: `sub("(.*)_(\\w+)__.*","\\2",A)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
a <- c("RHC3934__Bcell__.7DEA7B","RHC3944__Bcell__.7DEA7B",  "RHC3962__Tcell__.C6E879", "RHC4003__Bcell__.7DEA7B", "RHC4005__Bcell__.7DEA7B", "RHC4007__Bcell__.7DEA7B")

result <- str_match(a, "__(.*?)__")[,2]
```

output-

```
> result
[1] "Bcell" "Bcell" "Tcell" "Bcell" "Bcell" "Bcell"
```

If you specifically want **Bcell** then-

```
final_res <- result[result=="Bcell"]
```